# How to use central difference formula if step size is not constant

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods

In the problem I am solving, table values are given for function and it says to find $f''(0.5)$ using second order central difference formula. I know the formula which is
$\frac{f(x+\triangle x)-2f(x)+f(x-\triangle x)}{{\triangle x}^2}$. But the problem is, table values are as follows(I am listing values around $0.5$ only).

$f(0.48)=1.336, f(0.5)=1.405,f(0.51)=1.481$

I am confused what value should I use as $\triangle x$.

Comment: As that is obviously not possible, use the Taylor expansions to find a correct approximation formula. You could also just take the mean value of the first two as approximation of the missing value, but that might not give the best formula.

Comment: Make a quadratic equation and differentiate twice.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Is my formula correct? I mean I used mean value which gave me f(0.49) as 1.3705, and then by using formula I get $f''(0.5)$ as 415 but all the options are in between 57 to 61. Did I make any mistake

Comment: The central difference formula is correct. In my second idea I did not see immediately that $f(x-2h)+f(x)=2f(x-h)+f''(x-h)h^2+O(h^4)=2f(x-h)+f''(x)h^2+O(h^3)$ so that you get a second derivative term there that you need to transfer to the other side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply Taylor expansion to a general linear combination with coefficient sum zero, so that the constant terms cancel from the start.
\begin{align}
af(x+Δx)&−(a+b)f(x)+bf(x−2Δx)
\\
&=(a-2b)f'(x)Δx+\frac12(a+4b)f''(x)Δx^2+\frac16(a-8b)f'''(x)Δx^3+...
\end{align}
To remove the linear/first derivative term one needs $a=2b$, and the third order term does not cancel. The approximation formula is then
$$
f''(x)\approx\frac{2f(x+Δx)-3f(x)+f(x-2Δx)}{3Δx^2}
$$
Inserting values gives

```
(1.336-3*1.405+2*1.481)/(3*0.01**2) = 276.66666
```

Answer (score 1):

If, as I commented, you build the quadratic, working with whole numbers
$$f(x)=\frac{822}{25}-\frac{7927}{60}x+\frac{415}{3}x^2$$

So $$f''(x)=2\times\frac{415}{3}=276.66667$$